# how to get Bootstrap Modal to work? dependency issue?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to experiment with bootstrap modals and thought looking how an example was done would be a good place to start, however it does not seem to be working in my set-up at all but works on places like : https://www.bootply.com/rM2HVSUOtz#

My code is below, Im pretty sure I'm not referencing the jquery and bootstrap dependencies correctly but there's so many solutions and none explain how to know what you need...

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--CB-modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal --><!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Testing</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--modal-->
<script>
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
</script>



</html>
```

(The code even works on the snippet here but not at all within my project)

Comment: check in your page source that bootstrap CSS and js are loading.

Comment: Which version are you trying use? Bootstrap 4 requires jquery and popper.js. Read the [getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

Comment: @ZimSystem I'm using Bootstrap 4, specified in my dependencies inside package.json, I have the latest versions of jquery and popper their too

    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as shown below:

`run with this code` https://jsfiddle.net/r68fv56g/

Comment: I tried with this code and still the same result, nothing working in my set-up

where do I place
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
    })